# How to clear previous json response?

Tags: json, response

I need to clear the previous responses. It just piles up.

I am sorry, I have minimal knowledge about ajax.
I appreciate all of the responses. Thank you.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form").submit(function(){
            var selector = $(this);
            var form = selector.serializeArray();
            $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
            $.ajax({
                url:'{{ url('dashboard/add') }}',
                type: 'post',
                data: form,
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data){
                    if(!data.success)
                    {
                        $.each(data.errors, function(r, errors){
                            var node = document.createElement("li");
                            var textnode = document.createTextNode(errors);
                            node.appendChild(textnode);
                            document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node);

                        });

                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#myModal8').modal('show');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#myModal7').modal('show');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `ajax`, even less with `laravel`, and a very tentative relation to `json` and `response`: this is purely about `javascript` and `dom`...

Comment: Sorry. Looks like ajax kinda stuck in my head., I've been playing with it for almost 2 days, so I thought everything been linked with it. Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The responses are piling up because you keep appending them without ever clearing them. If you want to clear the error list whenever a new `submit` is started,

```
// ...
$("#form").submit(function(){
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "";
  // ...
```

Comment: Never thought of that. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

You are always appending to the same HTML list. 
Since you already have jquery you can use 
`empty()` to clear the list before appending to it.

```
$('#list').empty();
```

Be aware that this will delete everything inside the list, if you need to delete specific elements you should target their ids or class.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether any child nodes are present in the list using `hasChildNodes()` and if it is `true`, you can use `replaceChild()` instead of `appendChild()`.

Or you can empty the contents using `innerHTML` before appending something new.